# Prevent in between re-renders when using two State hooks connected by a useEffect hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have two State hooks s1, s2 and a useEffect hook updating s2 if the s1 is updated. How to prevent re-renders after s1 update and before s2 update?
The program depends on the coherence between s1 and s2 and having one change without the other causes errors.

I have the same problem but one of them is useCookies hook

I was expecting the useEffect to prevent the in between re-renders.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Your questions about code, i.e. debugging questions like these, are served by not only providing a general problem statement, but also the code itself, a [mre]. We are not clairvoyant, so we cannot help you to debug code you do not show us. Also showing what you have already tried to solve the problem is appreciated. [Edit] the question accordingly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: how about if you make `s2` derived based on a `useMemo` dependant on `s1`? This should take advantage of batching (React 18+). Note that this is only an optimisation and your code should work the same even with the additional renders. If it doesn't then there may be a logic fault somewhere

Comment: If you have 2 "states" that ***always*** update "together" then you basically have just 1 "state". Merge them into one single state and update both "state" values at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

> and a useEffect hook updating s2 if the s1 is updated

This is your problem, don't do this. [Docs explain how to remove the pattern this is common in many react codebases today](https://react.dev/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect#updating-state-based-on-props-or-state)

Right now you have something like this:

```
  const [state1,setState1] = useState()
  const [state2,setState2] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    if(state1 === 'something') setState2('somethingElse')
  },[state1]);

  // and somewhere down here you have:
  const handleSomeEvent = () => {
    setState1('something')
  }
```

You shouldn't use a `useEffect` to update dependent state in this way. `useEffect`'s are way overused. You should write your code like this:

```
  const [state1,setState1] = useState()
  const [state2,setState2] = useState()

  const handleSomeEvent = () => {
    setState1('something')
    if(/* some condition*/) setState2('somethingElse')
  }
```

No `useEffect`, same logic, updates are batched (so there is only one render).

[It's in the docs](https://react.dev/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect#how-to-remove-unnecessary-effects)

NOTE: In the contrived example I wrote above, you don't even need 2 pieces of state. It's entirely possible in your full example you don't need 2 pieces of state either if they can be synchronously updated together:

[Docs](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#storing-information-from-previous-renders):

> If the value you need can be computed entirely from the current props or other state, remove that redundant state altogether. If you’re worried about recomputing too often, the useMemo Hook can help.

Comment: and in the other case where state is updated after cookies is changed?

Comment: @Anonymous you'll have to post more realistic code to get an answer for your specific circumstances. I believe it's likely you don't even need state and can just derive it.

Answer (score -1):

Hope this will helps you.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [s1, setS1] = useState(initialS1);
  const [s2, setS2] = useState(initialS2);

  useEffect(() => {
    let timeoutId;
    const delay = 500;

    const updateS2 = () => {
      setS2(/* your update logic here */);
    };

    const debouncedUpdateS2 = () => {
      clearTimeout(timeoutId);
      timeoutId = setTimeout(updateS2, delay);
    };

    debouncedUpdateS2();

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    };
  }, [s1]);


  return (
    // your component
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer to Stack Overflow! However, please do read [answer]. "Hope this will helps (sic) you." is superfluous and obviously implied (you wouldn't have answered if it didn't help). Instead, [edit] the post to contain an explanation as to *why* this code solves the problem.

Comment: Additionally, this does not solve the problem. Actually, it makes it worse.